# MongoDB sort by custom calculation in Node.JS mongodb driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm Using Node.JS MongoDB driver. I have a collection of job lists with `salary` and `number of vacancies`, I want to sort them according to one rule, if either `salary` or `number of vacancies` are greater they will get top priority in sorting, and I came up with this simple formula

`( salary / 100 ) + num_of_vacancies`

eg:

Top priority ones

```
{ salary: 5000 , num_of_vacancies: 500 }   // value is 550
{ salary: 50000 , num_of_vacancies: 2 }    // value is 502
```

And Less priority for

```
{ salary: 5000 , num_of_vacancies: 2 }     // value is 52
```

But my Problem is, As far as I know, MongoDB sort takes arguments only to sort in ascending or descending order and a property to sort. How do I sort with custom expression.

The data in MongoDB looks like this // not the full varsion

```
{
    title:"job title",
    description:"job description",
    salary:5000,
    num_of_vacancy:50
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an option. Adjust it for a mongo driver.

- `$addFields` we create the field to sort, named toSortLater just for semantic purposes.
- add a `$sort` stage, and sort high values first. Change to 1 for the opposite behaviour.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$addFields:{ 
toSortLater:{
   $add:[
       {$divide:["$salary", 100]}, 
       "$num_of_vacancies"]
}}}, {$sort:{"toSortLater":-1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been looking for. I didn't knew it is possible to create temporary fields to store expressions.

Comment: @27px yes, that's the most powerful feature, called "aggregation". You can search in mongo docs, it's quite good.